# Why can I not reproduce a nd array manually?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I'm confused about these data structures.

From a GIS system, I use a function to extract the meta data (8 different fields)

```
myList = FeatureClassToNumPyArray(...)
myList = [('a', 'b', 'c'...) ('aa', 'bb', 'cc'...) ..]    # 8 fields
print (type(myList ))
print (myList.shape)
print (myList.size)
```

This produces:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1, 9893)
9893

# I was expecting to get (9893 rows x 8 cols), as in (8,9893)   
# or (9893, 8), but anyway, let's not worry about that right now.
```

So I try this:

```
>>> source = [('a', 'b', 'c') ('aa', 'bb', 'cc')]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

But throw in a comma separator, and it's fine... but now it's a list.

```
>>> source = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('aa', 'bb', 'cc')]
>>> type(source)
<class 'list'>
```

So, this magical GIS function can produce a data structure that is accepted as a numpy data array, but if I try create it manually, it's not possible.

What am I missing?

Comment: `myList = [('a', 'b', 'c'...) ('aa', 'bb', 'cc'...) ..]    # 8 fields` does not produce a `numpy.ndarray` object.  Probably, the function returns some form of structured, np.ndarray object. I'm not sure why you think this is "magic". But you really need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: So, clearly, this: `[('a', 'b', 'c') ('aa', 'bb', 'cc')]` is some printed string representation of the array. Why do you think that copy-pasting this string representation will construct an array? `str(some_object)` **will not return** a string that is valid Python source code. It *may*, but not necessarily. But definitely not with `numpy.ndarray` objects, so `print(np.array([1,2,2]))` and it won't print valid Python source code, let alone source code that will produce the same array.

Comment: But that's exactly what I said. The GIS function produces a dataset. If I ask for the type, then I'm told it is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. If I try manually it does not. I don;t know how to produce a reproducible example if you don't have the GIS system I am using...?

Comment: Again, **why do you expect `print(something)` to produce a string that is valid python source code to produce that object**? That is your fundamental assumption that is wrong. That is what you are missing. `print(repr(something))` will often get you something much closer, but it is never guaranteed to be valid source code. Again, likely it returns a `numpy.ndarray` with some structured dtype. What is `myList.dtype`? EDIT: so a very basic example, `something = object(); print(something)` now try to reproduce that from the string representation... there's no reason to expect to be able to.

Comment: "So, this magical GIS function can produce a data structure that is accepted as a numpy data array" No. The function *returns an array*. It isn't "accepted" as an array, **it already is a numpy array**. This is another key part of your misunderstanding. It is an array to begin with, and you printing it doesn't produce something that is an array, printing it prints *something* to the standard output device. Whatever that is has nothing to do with being an array.

Comment: OK, well that helps. It has been a niggle for me, which I have so far ignored, and what you say makes sense. I have walked into this with an overly simplistic preconceived idea of how things worked. I have ignored data types ...    I will have to re evaluate my understanding.

Comment: Again, it is almost certainly a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). Check the `.dtype`. And read the link for more understanding.

Comment: source = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('aa', 'bb', 'cc')] ==> out = np.array(source) ==> array([['a', 'b', 'c'],  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']], dtype='<U2') .  Now the first column... out[:, 0] ==>  array(['a', 'aa'], dtype='<U2').  Working with structured arrays are slightly different than ndarrays.  Refer to the numpy documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to do this, but the comment by juanpa.arrivillaga should be marked as the answer.

*Again, why do you expect print(something) to produce a string that is valid python source code to produce that object? That is your fundamental assumption that is wrong. That is what you are missing. print(repr(something)) will often get you something much closer, but it is never guaranteed to be valid source code. Again, likely it returns a numpy.ndarray with some structured dtype. What is myList.dtype? EDIT: so a very basic example, something = object(); print(something) now try to reproduce that from the string representation... there's no reason to expect to be able to. – juanpa.arrivillaga May 13 at 21:18*

My question originates from a fundamental misunderstanding of what a dataframe is and how it works. Took me  while to work it out.

In my words, it's an object that needs to be manipulated through various tools/functions... it's not just a matrix of "strings".