# How do I get an unknown np.ndarray object into a explicitly structured array?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Moving on from a previous question ([Why can I not reproduce a nd array manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61784860/why-can-i-not-reproduce-a-nd-array-manually?noredirect=1#comment109285774_61784860)) where I had to rethink my understanding....

How do I get this dataset into a form I need?

From a GIS system, I use a function to extract the meta data (8 different fields)

```
myList = FeatureClassToNumPyArray(...)

print (type(myList))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print (myList.shape)
(9893,)

print (myList.size)
9893

print (myList.dtype)
[('SiteID', '<U10'), ('Status', '<U10'), ('Name', '<U100')]
```

So, if I understand correctly, myList is **some** form of structured, np.ndarray object. But I want to get it into an explicitly structured object, so that I can modify it.

Since it has effectively 3 columns, how do I get it into the shape

```
myList.shape()
(9893,3)
```

Comment: Adding a sample of your data would help tremendously.

Comment: The basic structured array docs: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.rec.html.  Toward the bottom it documents a `numpy.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured` function that can be used convert your array into a (n,3) string dtype array.

Comment: in order to use structured_dto_unstructured, you need to ensure that the column/field data types are all the same.  If you have a mix of text, integers and floats, it won't be possible without slicing the columns into similar types.