# Is pandas and numpy any good for manipulation of non numeric data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've been going in circles for days now, and I've run out of steam. Doesn't help that I'm new to python / numpy / pandas etc.

I started with numpy which led me to pandas, because of a GIS function that delivers a numpy array of data. That is my starting point. I'm trying to get to an endpoint being a small enriched dataset, in an excel spreadsheet.

But it seems like going down a rabbit hole trying to extract that data, and then manipulate it with the numpy toolsets. The delivered data is one dimensional, but each row contains 8 fields. A simple conversion to pandas and then to ndarray, magically makes it all good. Except that I lose headers in the process, and it just snowballs from there.

I've had to revaluate my understanding, based on some feedback on another post, and that's fine. But I'm just going in circles. Example after example seems to use predominantly numerical data, and I'm starting to get the feeling that's where it's strength lies. My trying to use it for what I call more of a non-mathematical / numerical purpose looks like I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Any advice?

Addendum

The data I extract from the GIS system is names, dates, other textual data. I then have another csv file that I need to use as a lookup, so that I can enrich the source with more textual information which finally gets published to excel.

```
SAMPLE DATA - SOURCE

         WorkCode Status                      WorkName  StartDate    EndDate siteType              Supplier
0       AT-W34319   None               Second building 2020-05-04 2020-05-31 Type A                  Acem 1 
1       AT-W67713   None  Left of the red office tower 2019-02-11 2020-08-28 Type B               Quester Q
2       AT-W68713   None                12 main street 2019-05-23 2020-11-03 Class 1 Type B   Dettlim Group
3       AT-W70105   None                  city central 2019-03-07 2021-08-06 Other                 Hans Int
4       AT-W73855   None                     top floor 2019-05-06 2020-10-28 Type a                    None



SAMPLE DATA - CSV
["Id", "Version","Utility/Principal","Principal Contractor Contact"]

XM-N33463,7.1,"A Contracting company", "555-12345"
XM-N33211,2.1,"Contractor #b", "555-12345"
XM-N33225,1.3,"That other contractor", "555-12345"
XM-N58755,1.0,"v Contracting", "555-12345"
XM-N58755,2.3,"dsContracting", "555-12345"
XM-222222,2.3,"dsContracting", "555-12345"
BM-O33343,2.1,"dsContracting", "555-12345"



def SMAN():
    ####################################################################################################################
    # Exporting the results of the analysis...
    ####################################################################################################################


    """
    Approach is as follows:
    1) Get the source data 
    2) Get he CSV lookup data loaded into memory - it'll be faster
    3) Iterate through the source data, looking for matches in the CSV data
    4) Add an extra couple of columns onto the source data, and populate it with the (matching) lookup data. 
    5) Export the now enhanced data to excel.
    """

    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace + filenameGDB
    input = "ApprovedActivityByLocalBoard"
    exportFile = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(input, ['WorkCode', 'Status','WorkName', 'PSN2', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'siteType', 'Supplier'])

    # we have our data, but it's (9893,) instead of [9893 rows x 8 columns]

    pdExportFile = pandas.DataFrame(exportFile)
    LBW  = pdExportFile.to_numpy()                          
    del exportFile
    del pdExportFile

    # Now we have [9893 rows x 8 columns] - but we've lost the headers

    col_list = ["WorkCode", "Version","Principal","Contact"]
    allPermits = pandas.read_csv("lookup.csv", usecols=col_list)
    # Now we have the CSV file loaded ... and only the important parts - should be fast. 
    # Shape: (94523, 4)

    # will have to find a way to improve this...
    # CSV file has got more than WordCode, because there are different versions (as different records)
    # Only want the last one. 

    # each record must now be "enhanced" with matching record from the CSV file. 


    finalReport = []      # we are expecting this to be [9893 rows x 12 columns] at the end
    counter = -1
    for eachWorksite in LBW [:5]:    #let's just work with 5 records right now...
        counter += 1
        # eachWorksite=list(eachWorksite)       # eachWorksite is a tuple - so need to convert it 
        #                                       # but if we change it to a list, we lose the headers! 
        certID  = LBW [counter][0]              # get the ID to use for lookup matching 

        # Search the CSV data
        permitsFound = allPermits[allPermits['Id']==certID ]
        permitsFound = permitsFound.to_numpy()

    if numpy.shape(permitsFound)[0] > 1:
        print ("Too many hits!")            # got to deal with that CSV Version field. 
        exit()
    else:

        # now "enrich" the record/row by adding on the fields from the lookup
        # so a row goes from 8 fields to 12 fields 
        newline = numpy.append (eachWorksite, permitsFound)

        # and this enhanced record/row must become the new normal
        # but I cannot change the original, so it must go into a new container

        finalReport = numpy.append(finalReport, newline, axis = 0)

    # now I should have a new container, of "enriched" data
    # which as gone from [9893 rows x 8 columns] to [9893 rows x 12 columns]
    # Some of the columns of course, could be empty.


    #Now let's dump the results to an Excel file and make it accessible for everyone else. 

    df = pandas.DataFrame (finalReport)
    filepath = 'finalreport.csv'
    df.to_csv('filepath', index = False)

    # Somewhere I was getting Error("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
    # Now I get 
    filepath = 'finalReport.xlsx'
    df.to_excel(filepath, index=False)
```

Comment: what kind of things do you want to do to the non numerical data?

Comment: If you show a sample of the data, 5 rows and what you intend to get out from it then we can help.

Comment: `pd.read_csv` loads a `csv` into a DataFrame, with header information.  `np.genfromtxt` can also load the csv into a structured array - 1d with fields.  Both are useful for working data that has a diverse types of values in each column.  But you need to understand how structured arrays differ from ordinary (2d) numpy arrays.

Comment: Added some code, and sample data. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eventually answered my own question, and this is how:

1. Yes, for my situation, pandas worked just fine, even beautifully for
   manipulating non numerical data. I just had to learn some basics.
2. The biggest learning was to understand the pandas data frame as an object that has to be manipulated remotely by various functions/tools. Just because I "print" the dataframe, doesn't mean it's just text. (Thanks juanpa.arrivillaga for poitning out my erroneous assumptions) in [Why can I not reproduce a nd array manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61784860/why-can-i-not-reproduce-a-nd-array-manually)
3. I also had to wrap my mind around the concept of indexes and columns, and how they could be altered/manipulated/ etc. And then, how to use them to maximum effect.

Once those fundamentals had been sorted, the rest followed naturally, and my code reduced to a couple of nice elegant functions.

Cheers